# R label facet grid multiple line evolution

Tags: r, facet-grid

I have a data frame :

```
df2<-data.frame(taux=c(1.30,1.35,1.78,2.17,2.25,0.78,1.35,1.53,1.87,1.78),
                date=c("Y","M6","M3","M1","D1","Y","M6","M3","M1","D1"),
                Pays=c("US","US","US","US","US","Canada","Canada","Canada","Canada","Canada"))
```

I would like to make a graph with facet grid with the "Pays" in factor and "date" in abscisse. I would like only the line of the "Pays" in his facet. Some data has NA value.

Actually, I make

```
temp<-filter(df2,Pays=="US")
ylabs<-subset(temp,date==head(date,1))$Pays
yvals<-subset(temp,date==head(date,5))$taux[2]
temp<-transform(temp,date=factor(date))

us <- ggplot(temp,aes(x=date,y=taux))+
    geom_line(aes(group=Pays),colour="black")+
    geom_point(colour="white",size=8)+
    geom_text(aes(label=taux),size=3) +
    scale_y_continuous(name="",breaks=yvals+0.3,labels=ylabs)

us
```

And this for each "Pays", so I would like the same style of the graph but in facet grid with "Pays" in factor on the right (or the left). All my tries finished with all the value in each facet...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adjust the position of the facet labels you could use `?facet_wrap()` instead. The argument `strip.position` controls which side the labels will be written on.

Here is an example labeling on the "right", but you could change this to "left" or "bottom" too.

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x=date,y=taux))+
    geom_line(aes(group=Pays),colour="black")+
    geom_point(colour="white",size=8)+
    geom_text(aes(label=taux),size=3) +
    facet_wrap(~Pays, strip.position = "right")
```

[image]

`facet_wrap()` will also let you adjust the panel arrangement with the arguments `ncol`, `nrow`, and `dir` so you can have more control over the final output.

Or you can continue using `facet_grid()` like this, but you won't have as much control over the panel arrangement. The panels will be broken up along the y-axis.

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x=date,y=taux))+
    geom_line(aes(group=Pays),colour="black")+
    geom_point(colour="white",size=8)+
    geom_text(aes(label=taux),size=3) +
    facet_grid(Pays~.)
```

[image]